# Finding out whether a pathspec is a directory or file (or something else) through WMI?

Tags: .net, wmi

I have some C# code to get information about a file through WMI, which used to make the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Drive = 'C:' AND Path = '\\temp\\' AND FileName = 'testemef' AND Extension = 'txt'
```

I found out I can query both directories *and* files if I use the `CIM_LogicalFile` class instead:

```
SELECT * FROM CIM_LogicalFile WHERE Drive = 'C:' AND Path = '\\temp\\' AND FileName = 'testemef' AND Extension = 'txt'
```

I devised a roundabout way to determine whether the instance returned is a file or a directory: if I get an exception trying to access the `FileSize` property, it's a directory; if not, it's a file. I don't like this method, for there can be things other than directories and files. (Named pipes? Symlinks?)

Unfortunately, there's not any unique property in the `CIM_Directory` class that doesn't exist in the base `CIM_LogicalFile` class, so for now I'm reduced to knowing that something "is not a file", rather than "is a directory".

Is there a more airtight way in WMI to establish that a pathspec that's not a file is in fact a directory, rather than some other exotic entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the object's [`ClassPath.ClassName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementpath.classname.aspx) property (managed wrapper for the WMI system property [`__CLASS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394632.aspx)) - it returns *Win32_Directory* for folders and *CIM_DataFile* for files.